# Is -fprofile-reorder-functions supported with Autofdo?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization, perf, pgo

Autofdo allows gathering more accurate profile data than when using `-fprofile-generate` but it’s not used `-fauto-profile` unlike `-fprofile-use`.

Does it means it only works with `-fprofile-use`?